# FireBase - FIRDataEventTypeValue boack suddenly stopped working

Tags: objective-c, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and i am working since last week on firebase, i have implemented insert data and delete data queries and it was working fine but suddenly on friday morning it has stopped working now below block is not working any more can anyone please help me :

```
FIRDatabaseHandle handlerChildAdded = [data observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. I have updated pod and again it start working as before.